# Changing eclipse menu buttons font color

Tags: eclipse, color-scheme

I just downloaded the eclipse moonrise theme for my eclipse. 
the problem is the color of the text on the menu buttons is white on grey and i can't read them. tried to change different color is colors and fonts tab with no success.

[image]
any one know where to change this font?

Thanks

Comment: I am looking for a solution to this issue as well.